# Changing filename before upload to AWS S3 in Angular6

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am using below example to get my files uploaded to AWS s3 server: https://grokonez.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-how-to-upload-file-to-s3-bucket

Here in example files are getting uploaded with the same name as it is whereas I just like to upload with an auto-generated name. Is it possible to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to provide the key name different from the actual file name you are uploading.

const params = {
      Bucket: 'jsa-angular4-bucket',
      Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
      Body: file
    };

// here in key instead of file.name, you provide the name that you want it to be.